# IE doesn't send POST data

Tags: internet-explorer, codeigniter, post

IE 6 and any other version of IE stopped sending POST data since some undefined moment in the past. Reinstalling doesn't help. xdebug shows empty $_POST, profiler echoes empty array.

FF and Opera work fine on the same PC at the same time.

Case is WinXP, IE6, IE8, CodeIgniter 1.7.2, Apache 2, PHP 5.2.4

Comment: Do you have any javascript on the page?

Answer (score 0):

Firs of all ,you should write your code here.
I think its "form" problem